# What sort of mount would a naga use and how?

Tags: fantasy-races, fauna, transportation, mounts

Is there any sort of animal (living or extinct) that would be a practical mount for a naga? And how would they be able to ride it? Or is this not a workable idea at all and should I throw out the idea of nagas riding mounts entirely and stick to them being pulled in carts when needed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look up the history of sidesaddle riding. It's been around a long time and there's no reason your naga can't do the very same thing, which means the issue is the saddle, not the mount, and they can ride anything available.

Comment: naga: "where's the seatbelt and why is there a pillar here?"

Comment: What kind of naga are you talking about?

Comment: Please provide more details about your nagas.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't a naga be able to ride a horse? Not very comfortably probably, but still able. Also: people don't naturally fit horses. Legs and back hurts if you're not used to it. Saddles help. I understand a naga would weigh more than a standard person and probably would rather 'sit' on something more flat than a horse back. In that case: elephants? Lots of room for a flat or concave saddle and the weight isn't a problem.
As to extinct animals: Dinosaurs or some animals with big scales, long horns, tusks (like elephants) or some other pointy features could be potentially enough for a naga to distribute its weight on multiple of those? Such features are usually found on an animal's head though and head isn't the best place to sit on for an animal.